# TextView content is clipped on the right side

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

This is my custom dialog layout:

```
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Because of the @+id/icon the @+id/text goes out of the grid layout on the right side. AND I want the icon to have the same width as the height of the dialog (like a square). Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="28sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
```